JWT token in Back for front in nestJS
I'm using front-end app that create JWT token and sending it to back for front (BFF) in nestjs.
Then, my BFF use Axios to call one or multiple url in my back end app (spring-boot) with the JWT token inside all the http calls.
Problem:
In my front end i have page where i can put comments and sometimes the comment is save with the name of another connected user.
Here is my NestInterceptor :
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as https from 'https';

export class AuthorizationHandlingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<unknown> {
    // Récupérer la requête
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    if (request) {
      const token = request.headers['authorization'];
      const tenant = request.headers['x-tenant'];

      if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
      }
      if (tenant) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Tenant'] = tenant;
      }
    }
    return next.handle();
  }
}


As i have see for the moment is that not a good practice to use axios.defaults.headers.common
I have see that i can to use NestMiddleware to save the token in AsyncLocalStorage and then in my interceptor i read the asynclocalstorage to get back my token and put it in
axios.defaults.headers.common
I have see that i need to create a new Axios request each time i call my back-end but create a new axios request and put the bad token in it doesn't change the problem i think...
Does anyone know the best practices for doing this? and that the tokens are correctly associated with the initial request?
Thanks
